# CSS Flowbite - unable to get the components to align properly

Tags: css, tailwind-css, flowbite

I'm using some of the flowbite components and I'm unable to figure out how to get the components to align properly. I'm using two components: ([sidebar with navbar](https://flowbite.com/docs/components/sidebar/#sidebar-with-navbar)) and ([table with modal](https://flowbite.com/docs/components/tables/#table-with-modal)). However, I'm unable to get it to a state where the table is centered - it keeps overlapping with the navbar today so I only see a part of the table.

Here's the two main div components and css across both of the elements and I've tried everything from making the components absolute, adding padding, moving left/bottom, and nothing has worked. Curious if anyone can help me figure it out.

```
<nav class="fixed top-0 z-50 w-full bg-white border-b border-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
    
<div class="relative overflow-x-auto shadow-md sm:rounded-lg">
```

The issues is that when I try to edit the table css and adding padding left or align it left, nothing happens. I've even tried it in isolation without the the sidebar - and while I can move the direction from the top, I'm just not able to move it to the right - which is a problem.